# Error: NodeJS Expected property shorthand object-shorthand

Tags: node.js

The code is as

```
72 -> users.forEach(function(user) {
73 ->      data1.push([{ user_id1: user_id1, user_id2: user, status: 'RequestSent' }])
74 ->      data2.push([{ user_id1: user, user_id2: user_id1, status: 'RequestPending' }])
75 ->    }
```

72..75 are the line numbers.

The error I am getting is as
`##[error]  73:21  error  Expected property shorthand  object-shorthand`

How to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's only a linting error, not a runtime error. It's telling you that, in ES6, rather than repeating a property name whose value should be a variable of the same name with `prop: prop`, you can just use `prop` in an object literal. Use:

```
data1.push([{
  user_id1,
  user_id2: user,
  status: 'RequestSent'
}]);
data2.push([{
  user_id1: user,
  user_id2: user_id1,
  status: 'RequestPending'
}]);
```